# How can I use adapter-static in SvelteKit to prerender my site without calling LayoutLoad in parallel?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, prerender

I have a SvelteKit site that uses `adapter-static` to prerender pages.
It's a multilingual site, so I pass the paths `/`, `/de`, `/es`, `pt` in `svelte.config.js`. For translation I use `sveltekit-i18n`.

I have

- `routes/+page.svelte`,
- `routes/de/+page.svelte`,
- `routes/es/+page.svelte`
- `routes/pt/+page.svelte`

The problem is `sveltekit-i18n` and most i18n libraries use a reactive variable `$t` and when the pages are built, it runs the LayoutLoad functions in parallel for these sites.
In my LayoutLoad (routes/layout.ts) and LayoutServerLoad (routes/+layout.server.ts)` I have something like this:

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
export async function load(attrs: any) {
    const startsWith = ['pt', 'es', 'de'].find((e) => attrs?.url?.pathname.startsWith(`/${e}`));

    const locale = startsWith ?? defaultLocale;
    await loadTranslations(initLocale, attrs?.url?.pathname);
    return { locale };
}
```

and this

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutLoad} */
export async function load({ data, url, parent }: any) {
    await loadTranslations(data.locale, url?.pathname);
    return { locale: data.locale };
}
```

now when I build my site with SvelteKit via `vite build` then I find out that the load functions are loaded like this by using console.log

layout.server.ts es /es
layout.server.ts pt /pt
layout.server.ts de /de
layout.ts es /es
layout.ts pt /pt
layout.svelte es /es
**page.svelte pt /es**

layout.ts de /de
layout.svelte de /de
page.svelte de /de
layout.svelte pt /pt
**page.svelte de /pt**

layout.server.ts en /
layout.ts en /
layout.svelte en /
page.svelte en /

as you can see the page `/es/+page.svelte` has suddenly the language `pt` and not `es`.
 The same applies to the page `/pt/+page.svelte` it suddenly has the language German `de`.
 I believe this is due to the reactivity of the `$t` variable in i18n libraries like sveltekit-i18n, but I also don't know how to fix it, as load functions seem to be loaded in parallel and not right before the `+page.svelte` is being built.
So what happens I have in my prerendered output html files the wrong language, for example in meta description tags etc.
I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I replicated the issue using a skeleton SvelteKit project, I noticed that I had set the **concurrency level** to **3** in prerender options in `svelte.config.js`. This causes the mixed order of load runs above, setting it to **1** solved the problem.

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess({
        sass: true,
        postcss: true
    }),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        prerender: {
            concurrency: 1, // had to be set to 1 instead of 3
            crawl: true,
            entries: pages
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but during DB initialisation instead.

The solution I applied was to filter the code with the [building variable](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-building). For example:

```
import { building } from '$app/environment';

if (!building) {
  // Connect to the DB
}
```

In your case, you might want to wrap the `loadTranslations` to prevent it from running.

Comment: just wrapping it doesn't work sadly, maybe it's possible to load all translations during build using the `building` variable and change the locale based on pathname, but where do I set the locale, and will the three parallel calls to layout.server.ts if I do it there not override each others setting?

Comment: Mmm... maybe I misunderstood you. Please, could you explain where did you set the `console.log` to get the provided log? Also, why aren't you using the `params` instead of inspecting the URL?

Comment: I have replicated the issue, using a skeleton SvelteKit project one using `sveltekit-intl-precompile` and the other using `sveltekit-i18n` as above, both did not have the issue. When I tried to use the same prerender options as in my `svelte.config.js`, I noticed I had set the `concurrency` level to 3. Thus we have the mixed order of load runs above, setting it to 1 solved the problem.

Comment: thanks for your insights, intially I was using `params` and somehow thought it could be related to my issue, in any case you helped me a lot